# Parse Out Last Sequence Of Numbers From Pandas Column to create new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with codes like the following and would like to create a new column that has the last sequence of numbers parse out.

```
array(['K9ADXXL2', 'K9ADXL2', 'K9ADXS2', 'IVERMAXSCM12', 'HPDMUDOGDRYL'])
```

So the new column would contain the following:

```
array([2,2,2,12,None])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample data

```
df:

          codes
0      K9ADXXL2
1       K9ADXL2
2       K9ADXS2
3  IVERMAXSCM12
4  HPDMUDOGDRYL
```

Use `str.extract` gets digits at the end of string and passing to `pd.to_numeric`

```
pd.to_numeric(df.codes.str.extract(r'(\d+$)')[0], errors='coerce')

Out[11]:
0     2.0
1     2.0
2     2.0
3    12.0
4     NaN
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

---

If you want get value as string of numbers, you may use `str.extract` or  `str.findall` as follow

```
df.codes.str.findall(r'\d+$').str[0]
```

or

```
df.codes.str.extract(r'(\d+$)')[0]

Out[20]:
0      2
1      2
2      2
3     12
4    NaN
Name: codes, dtype: object
```

Comment: @ScottBoston: yours is  a good answer, too :). However, I think slicing on `[0]` isn't different much from `T`. I also assume OP knows how to get array or list from Series so I give the Series output.

Answer (score -1):

```
import re
import pandas as pd


def get_trailing_digits(s):
    match = re.search("[0-9]+$",s)
    return match.group(0) if match else None

original_column = pd.array(['K9ADXXL2', 'K9ADXL2', 'K9ADXS2', 'IVERMAXSCM12', 'HPDMUDOGDRYL'])
new_column = pd.array([get_trailing_digits(s) for s in original_column])
# ['2', '2', '2', '12', None]
```

`0-9]` means any digit

`+` means one or more times

`$`means only at the end of the string

You can use the apply function of a series/data frame with get_trailing_digits as the function.
eg.

`my_df["new column"] = my_df["old column"].apply(get_trailing_digits)`